# \docsvlist not work with list in form of macro

Tags: tex-core, loops, etoolbox

In the following codes, I tries three methods to build a csv list(a sequence of natural numbers from 1 to 5).

Then I use `\docsvlist`(from `etoolbox`) to wrap each element of the list with `parentheses`.

All these tries fail(Please refer to the codes). Why and how to make them work as expected?

**Codes:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\do}[1]{(#1)}

% Method 1 to build a csv list
\def\aaa{1,2,3,4,5}

% Method 2 to build a csv list
\def\bbb{%
\newcount\foo
\foo=1
\loop
\ifnum \foo=5 5\else%
\the\foo,%
\advance \foo 1%
\repeat}

% Method 3 to build a csv list
\NewDocumentCommand\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{mO{,}m}{%
  %{#1-start number}，[#2-dilimiter]，{#3-end number}
  \ifnum#1=#3 #3%
  \else%
  #1#2\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{\number\numexpr #1+1}[#2]{#3}%
  \fi%
}
\def\ccc{\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{1}{5}}

\begin{document}
% Code 1: 
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\aaa}\\
Q1: typeset 12345, not desired (1)(2)(3)(4)(5), why?
\bigskip

% Code 2:
bbb is : \bbb\\ %typeset 1,2,3,4,5 as expected
\docsvlist\bbb\\ %typeset 1,2,3,4,5, not desired (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\bbb}\\ %This causes error
Q2: What's wrong with the above line of code?
\bigskip

% Code 3:
ccc is: \ccc\\ %typeset 1,2,3,4,5 as expected
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\ccc}\\
Q3: Why does the above line of code typeset 1,2,3,4,5, not desired (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
\end{document}
```

Comment: dont use `%` like this: `\advance \foo 1%` you force `\repeat` to be seen before the additio is done.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle I don't quite understand why the `%` make `\repeat` be seen before the addition is done? Would you say more about it?

Comment: try putting a 2 on the line after 1 and you will see with `%` it adds 12 as the % means the number literal does not end so it expands the next line looking for more digits. You could just use a built in latex clist here, etoolbox should be considered a legacy package thse days: far more powful functionality is available without any package

Comment: Also, don't do `\newcount\foo` inside of a macro, this way each time you use the surrounding macro you block an additional count register. Just do `\newcount\foo` once outside any macro and use it in your macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to being a macro: a simple `\docsvlist{a,b,c}` would fail the same way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



% Method 1 to build a csv list
\def\aaa{1,2,3,4,5}

% Method 2 to build a csv list
\def\bbb{%
\newcount\foo % would be better outside
\foo=1
\loop
\ifnum \foo=5 5\else%
\the\foo,%
\advance \foo 1 % space before % needed
\repeat}

% Method 3 to build a csv list
\NewDocumentCommand\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{mO{,}m}{%
  %{#1-start number}，[#2-dilimiter]，{#3-end number}
  \ifnum#1=#3 #3%
  \else%
  #1#2\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{\number\numexpr #1+1}[#2]{#3}%
  \fi%
}
\def\ccc{\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{1}{5}}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\do}[1]{(#1)}
\docsvlist{a, b, c}

% Code 1: 
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\aaa}\\
Q1: typeset 12345, not desired (1)(2)(3)(4)(5), why?
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

`\do` is a core latex command redefined at arbitrary places (and in `\begin{document}`) for all kinds of list processing, so you can only use this if you set `\do` immediately before the process. Uncomment the definition of `\do` and you will see both lists work.

`\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\ccc}`

is

`\docsvlist{\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{1}{5}}`

which can not work, `\docsvlist` needs the `,` in the arguument.

---

LaTeX has built in functions for mapping over comma lists that make this much easier

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% no package needed

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\listmap\clist_map_inline:nn
\let\listvarmap\clist_map_inline:Nn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn {e }
\let\listexpmap\clist_map_inline:en
\let\intmap\int_step_inline:nnnn
\let\addtolist\clist_put_right:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% map over a list
\listmap{aa,bb,cc}{(#1)}

% list in variable
\def\aaa{11,22,33}

% map over the variable's value
\listvarmap\aaa{(#1)}

% expand to a list, then map
\listexpmap{www,xx,\aaa,zz}{(#1)}

% Numeric loop
% {<start>} {<step>} {<end>} {<code>}
\intmap{5}{1}{10}{(#1)}

% you almost certainly don't need this, build list first
\edef\bbb{}
\intmap{8}{-2}{0}{\addtolist\bbb{item#1}}
\listvarmap\bbb{(#1)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As for `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\ccc}`, why does "`\edef`\ccc{\SequenceOfNaturalNumbers{1}{5}}" with `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\ccc}` also not get desired result?

Comment: @lyl You can not put arbitrary latex constructs in an `\edef` in particular `\NewDocumentCommand` defined commands are `\protected` so they do not expand in an `\edef`. Really you should use a clist which takes care of all these details.

Comment: @lyl clist example added

Comment: Two macros(\clist_map_inline:nn` and `\clist_map_inline:Nn`) are use for explicit list and list in form of macro repectively. I wnoder if there is similar macro working for both.

Comment: @lyl it is really bad style to work with both for generic lists, if `\aaa,\bbb` is a two item list, how do you know if `\aaa` is a one item list or a macro to be expanded.  However if your macros are expandable and you want lists of non expandable tokens use `e` instead of `N` or `n` that will expand everything (like `\edef`) first, I added that version

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle so much for your expl3 codes which solve the second part of my question - how to traverse each element of a list. And back to my first part of the question - how to build a sequence of natural numbers and store it in a expandable macro for later use. After modified to `\advance \foo 1 % space before % needed`, `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\bbb}` still causes error(`Incomplete \ifx`). The try of `\clist_map_inline:Nn \bbb{(#1)}` cause error either.

Comment: @lyl it makes no sense to construct a comma list of numbers then procsses that list. why not just process the numbers in the initial loop, imagine printing the first 1000 numbers, you could loop 1 ..1000 and print each item, or you could loop 1..1000 building an expensive list structure then do a slower comma  list iteration over the list printing each item, but apart from being much slower and taking much more memory why choose the second way?

Comment: traversal is only one of the uses of a list. In my project, the list is also for ohter uses, extract a certain element for example. That is the reason why a list need to be built first and store it in a expandable macro.

Comment: @lyl x-y-problem spotted :) If you have a list of natural numbers, getting element *n* is really just the same as calculating *n* \* *s* + *o* with *s* the step size and *o* the offset. And for mapping to a sequence of natural numbers you can use the `expl3` function `\int_step_inline:nnnn` with the arguments `{<start>} {<step>} {<end>} {<code>}` (and in `<code>` you refer to the current number with `#1` just like for the `\clist_map_inline:nn` function).

Comment: @lyl I can't see why you need it but I added a version building a comma list from a numeric loop then mapping over the list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\cs_new_eq:NN` instead of `\let`?

Comment: @egreg well I did wonder about not using either and having the loops in expl3 which would be more realistic, just having a document level command for some higher level thing, but OP gave no hint about intended use and has I guess existing 2e code into which this could be dropped with minimal disruption so I wanted to give a flavour of that mixed use.